# Conditional merging of 2 pandas dataframes wiith no overlapping variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge two dataframes with conditions and one to many relationships.

The dataframes do not have an overlapping column as I am working with coordinate data.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Label': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                    'x_low': [101940675,101947985,101941345,101948789],
                    'x_high': [101940777,10194855,101941577,101949111],
                    'y_low': [427429081, 427429000, 427429596, 427429466],
                    'y_high': [427429089, 427429001, 427429599, 427429467]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Image': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                    'X': [101948445, 101948467, 101948764, 101947896, 101941234],
                    'Y': [427429082, 427429001, 427429597, 427429467, 427430045]})
df1

    Label   x_low   x_high  y_low   y_high
0   A   101940675   101940777   427429081   427429089
1   B   101947985   10194855    427429000   427429001
2   C   101941345   101941577   427429596   427429599
3   D   101948789   101949111   427429466   427429467

df2 

Image   X   Y
0   1   101948445   427429082
1   2   101948467   427429001
2   3   101948764   427429597
3   4   101947896   427429467
4   5   101941234   427430045
```

I want to merge the datasets with the condition that the X and Y coordinates from df2 have to be between the corresponding _low and _high values of df1. I would also like to know if multiple coordinate pairs would form one to many relationships.

desired output would look something like this:

```
Label   x_low   x_high  y_low   y_high  Image   X   Y
0   B   101947985   101948555   427429000   427429002   2   101948467   427429001
1   B   101947985   101948555   427429000   427429002   3   101948477   427429008
2   D   101948789   101949111   427429466   427429467   5   101941234   427430045
```

I tried merging both the whole dataframes but they have 3000 and 30000 lines so I dont have the memory available. Tried multiple other methods but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: your data does not look right - the x_high is lower than x_low for some values? with the data you shared, there will be no matches